# How to get a function's return value after the :e command in Vim

Tags: vim

I wrote a function to get the full path of the current file under the cursor

```
nmap <F12> :echo GetFullPath()<cr>
function! GetFullPath()
    let currentFile=expand("<cfile>")
    let afterChangeSlash=substitute(currentFile,"/","\\","g")
    let fullPath="e:\\Test\\".afterChangeSlash
    return fullPath
endfunction
```

When I call the function after the :echo command, I get the expected result,like:

```
:echo GetFullPath()
```

**e:\Test\test.h**

However,When I call it after the :e(edit) command:

```
:e GetFullPath()
```

Vim just create a new file named **GetFullPath()**

Why the command :e  will treat a function call literally while the command :echo won't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`:execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute) to build your ex command string and execute it:

```
:exe "e ".GetFullPath()
```

Or use the [`=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#%60=) syntax to expand a Vim expression:

```
:e `=GetFullPath()`
```

If you check the help for `:edit` and `:echo`, you'll notice that the former expects its argument to be the file name (literally), while `:echo` expects an expression which will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Some ex commands expect to be given an expression, while some others expect to be given a string. For your case to make it work use exec:

```
nmap <F12> :exec 'e ' . GetFullPath()
```